# Is this htaccess rewrite correct?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following in my `htaccess` file. What I'm trying to do is to make

`domain.com/index.php/view/whatever` accessable via  `domain.com/whatever`
and also redirect from `non www` to `www`.

This works for all urls that have `index.php/view` in them but now other URLs that don't have `index.php/view` in them are breaking not working. Ex: `domain.com/index.php/site/pages` no longer works since it doesn't have `index.php/view` in it.

I want htaccess to only affect those URLs that have `index.php/view` in them and not anything else. What do I need to do to fix that?

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/view/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{http_host} ^domain.com [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

**UPDATE.** To narrow things down, How can i have both rules like so. i need them both

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/view/$1 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/site/$1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if a request is made to something like http://domain.com/index.php/site/pages, you want it to pass through untouched, but if it's something like http://domain.com/whatever, you want it to get rewritten?

The first rule you have there matches everything (except files and directories). You probably want to narrow the RewriteRule with something like:

RewriteRule !^index.php /index.php/view/$1 [L]

HTH

Neal

Comment: No this doesn't solve it. To narrow down the question, how can i have both rule `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/view/$1`  and `^(.*)$ /index.php/site/$1`. I can only seem to have one of them. I need them both

Comment: I don't really think you can have them both, you would probably have to do something like: `RewriteRule ^site/(.*)$ /index.php/view/$1` and `RewriteRule ^view/(.*)$ /index.php/site/$1`

Comment: You can't have each URL rewritten two ways, and mod_rewrite has no way of knowing which way is correct.